# SVG with images with dataURL href not rendered correctly in some engine

Tags: pdf, canvas, svg, data-uri

This SVG originated from HTML5 canvas. Which looks fine and I added  images that are represented in `dataurl` form to avoid CORS issues.

1. However, when opened in chrome the image showed up fine
2. When opened in Adobe Illustrator, the image did not show up.
3. When opened with macOS preview app, the image did not show up.

I looked up SVG2 specifications for using dataURL in svg's `<image>` tag `href` attribute and they said its okay to use. So I don't understand what is causing this rendering discrepancy between different viewers.

[File for reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LuLXLSttffFnI5mQncpYGvZqYMlljXz8/view)

In short, what is the standard way to embed images into SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found out it is because only Chrome supports the newer SVG2 standard `href` attribute on `<image>` element of SVG. So I just needed to replace the `href` with `xlink:href`

Even though `xlink:href` attribute is deprecated in SVG2. It seems the other softwares aforementioned in the question are not SVG2-compliant.